# I'm trying to increment a count value in DynamoDB each time my lambda is triggered by SNS

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have an empty table in DynamoDb with an id as a primary key and time as a sort key. I am trying to count the number of sns messages coming through. I have the code below but it's just creating every value within my count column as 1. With every added value or incoming sns message, I want a row that counts each total incoming sns message and update accordingly like 1 in one row for first message,2 in the next, 3 in the next and so forth. This is boto3 python. I'm a beginner but this what I have so far. I want the pattern below each time sns triggers lambda. I'm also wondering if I can just have one value as count that gets updated with the sum?

```
id ---- time ---SNS count
4545    12:00pm  1
8569    1:00pm   2
1234    2:00pm   3
```

````
response = table.update_item(
     Key={
         "itemID": itemID,
         "time": time
     },
     UpdateExpression ='ADD count :inc',
     ExpressionAttributeValues={
        ':inc': 1

     },
     ReturnValues="UPDATED_NEW"
 )
 
 print(response)
 ```
````

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking for isn't something that is really supported in DynamoDB. You can have a separate record that holds the current count, and increment that in the way you've done it above, but with a key that will be the same all the time. In so doing, you could get the new value and put that value in the new record. It would look something like this (pardon my lack of Python skills).

```
response = table.update_item(
     Key={
         "itemID": 0, # this is a placeholder ID, it just needs to be some value that won't be used elsewhere
         "time": 'NOT A REAL TIME' # again, a placeholder. since this is just stored as a string it can be anything
     },
     UpdateExpression ='ADD count :inc',
     ExpressionAttributeValues={
        ':inc': 1
     },
     ReturnValues="UPDATED_NEW"
 )

table.put_item(
     Item={
         "itemID": itemID,
         "time": time,
         "count": response['count']
     }
 )
```

There is an inherit danger here. The `update_item` could succeed and the `put_item` could fail, causing your count to be wrong. Also, if you process the same SNS record more than once you would have an incorrect value.

All that said, you might want to consider what it is you are really needing here. You may find that there are better options, like maybe using DynamoDB streams to update counts.